# Printing memory address format changed?

Tags: gdb

Today, when I wanted to print 8 bytes from a memory address, I entered and received the following

---

```
(gdb) x/8x 0x55683298
0x55683298 <_reserved+1036952>: 0xa8 0x32 0x68 0x55 0xec 0x73 0xfc 0xf7
```

---

Last month, if I were to have done the same print command, I would have received a different print format.

```
0x55683298 <_reserved+1036952>: 0x556832a8 0xf7fc73ec
```

---

How can I get that old printing format back? Also, any ideas as to why it changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get that old printing format back?

```
(gdb) x/wx 0x55683298

(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char), s(string)
  and z(hex, zero padded on the left).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.

Defaults for format and size letters are those previously used.
Default count is 1.  Default address is following last thing printed
with this command or "print".
```

Note in particular the "previously used" part:

```
(gdb) x/x &main
0x4004ed <main>:    0xe5894855
(gdb) x/c &main
0x4004ed <main>:    85 'U'
(gdb) x/x &main
0x4004ed <main>:    0x55   <<=== new default is 'c'!
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the change? What was the project trying to fix? (I can't understand why a function pointer *would not* be best represented by `%p`).

Comment: @jww There was *no* change. GDB has worked that way for many years. *You* examined memory in a different way, and that different way is "sticky" in a way you didn't expect.

Comment: @jww I just ran it again and it "fixed" itself. Yeah so I must have at some point done "x/8bx", so it stuck.